# JPA criteriaBuilder for @Embeddable classes containing @ManyToOne relationships

Tags: java, jpa, metamodel

This is my entity with composite foreign key as PK.

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "privilege_per_role")
    public class PrivilegePerRole extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
        PrivilegePerRoleKey privilegePerRoleKey;

        @Embeddable
        public static class PrivilegePerRoleKey implements Serializable {

            /**
             * Default Constructor
             */
            public PrivilegePerRoleKey() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            /**
             * Generated serial UID
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 3511215419L;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_name", referencedColumnName = "privilege_name", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
            @JsonBackReference("thePrivilege")
            private Privilege thePrivilege;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_name", referencedColumnName = "role_name", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
            @JsonBackReference("theRole")
            private Role theRole;
        }
    }
```

Everything is ok and mvn generate source produce the following MetaModel:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(PrivilegePerRole.class)
public abstract class PrivilegePerRole_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<PrivilegePerRole, PrivilegePerRoleKey> privilegePerRoleKey;

    public static final String PRIVILEGE_PER_ROLE_KEY = "privilegePerRoleKey";
}
```

**NOTE:** I have not the Metamodel of the EmbeddedClass.

Now, i would like to find all PrivilegePerRole that have a Privilege.name = "pippo".

**What is the best practice to get them using embedded class?**

With a common related entity i would write:

```
(root, query, cBuilder) -> cBuilder.equal(root.get(PrivilegePerRole_.privilege).get(Privilege_.name), "pippo")
```

but i have no idea how to achive same result with embedded class.